# While creating Azure SQL DB server, "This location is not available for subscriptions"

Tags: azure, location

I've tried to create Azure SQL database server but, while I'm setting the detail of server for location, it keep saying that  "This location is NOT available for subscriptions". I tried every location, but NONE of them worked. How should I fix this issue? 
FYI, My subscription is only Azure for Students and I don't have any databse server on my account. I am a brand new user.

Comment: Possible Azure VM (?) outage for 24hrs or so, in all regions..

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac0376cb-2a0e-4dc2-a52c-d986989e6801/unable-to-create-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is having capacity issues right now and they are having this issue with all "free tier" and "Azure for Students" subscriptions. I believe they have done this to free up the capacity for subscriptions.

Please follow this link for most up to details from Microsoft support: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac0376cb-2a0e-4dc2-a52c-d986989e6801/ongoing-issue-unable-to-create-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 0):

Yes , azure pass not working. You need to purchase the azure access with the MOC on market place  or redeem using your MCT access .

Answer (score 0):

From: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac0376cb-2a0e-4dc2-a52c-d986989e6801/unable-to-create-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted

> Thank you for your interest in Azure SQL Database.
>
> Due to high demand for capacity in our datacenters, availability is limited for >customers using free benefit subscriptions.
>
> We are working on adding more capacity and will provide more updates on this ?>thread.
>
> Thank you for your understanding.

It sounds that this is due to Covid-19 and the following statement: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

> "As demand continues to grow, if we are faced with any capacity constraints in any region during this time, we have established clear criteria for the priority of new cloud capacity. Top priority will be going to first responders, health and emergency management services, critical government infrastructure organizational use, and ensuring remote workers stay up and running with the core functionality of Teams. We will also consider adjusting free offers, as necessary, to ensure support of existing customers." You can use the Azure Portal to raise your request to access to a region. The access will be checked from case to case and access to locations given.